# pine - how to extract the value of the first element of a series

Tags: time-series, pine-script

I have a series of prices, which has gone through several calculations and maninpulations.

I now want to obtain the single float value of the first element from this series, in order to perform further formula calculations.

I  use:

```
avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var  = avg_ratio_Log_Daily[0]
```

However, `avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var` is **returned as a new series, not a single float value.**

What is the correct way / syntax to obatian this?

Answer (score 0):

```
indicator("First Element Value", overlay=true)
```

Assuming avg_ratio_Log_Daily is your series

```
var avg_ratio_Log_Daily = // Your series calculation will be here
```

Extract the value of the first element

```
var float avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var = avg_ratio_Log_Daily[0]
```

Use avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var in further calculations or plotting

```
plot(avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: I think you are reffering to python.

Comment: My question is about pine script

Comment: I recive nans.......

Comment: var float avg_ratio_Log_Daily_var = avg_ratio_Log_Daily[0]
This returns type series.....